# Getting java.io.FileNotFoundException when template client is in subdirectory

Tags: templates, jsf, facelets, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to navigate to an administration page which has a sub directory under the webcontent folder and receiving an java.io.FileNotFoundException.  Using Glassfish 3.1.1.

My

```
    war File:
         index.xhtml
         login.xhtml
         /admin/admin.xhtml
```

the link i am using is:

```
       <h:link value="Admin" outcome="admin/admin.xhtml"/>
```

I was hoping implicit naviagtion would be able to handle this?

Thanks in advance,

Scott

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `<h:link>` looks perfectly fine, although I would just trim off the `.xhtml` extension to minimize boilerplate and FacesServlet mapping ambiguity which JSF already takes care of for you.

You need to *read* the message of the `FileNotFoundException` which you got there. My cents on that it actually points to the template file which you're using in `<ui:composition template>` of `admin/admin.xhtml`. You'd like to specify an absolute path in there, i.e. starting with `/`, so that it's resolved relative to the root of the web content, otherwise it's resolved relative to the location of the current template client.

E.g. thus **not** so:

```
<ui:composition template="WEB-INF/admintemplate.xhtml">
```

which would search for `/admin/WEB-INF/admintemplate.xhtml`, but rather so:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/admintemplate.xhtml">
```

Note that this is not related to implicit navigation. You would have exactly the same problem when opening the page directly.